# How do I merge excel cells using ASP

Tags: sql-server, excel, asp-classic

I am using ASP to Import data from SQL server and then export it to excel.

I though want a header text in row 1 ie cells a1 to n1
But how do I write command that can merge those fields ?
then I would be able to insert my header txt.

I have this asp code:

```vb
'setup the excel file
Dim objFSO, objExcelFile
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 excelfilename = "Financials_clients_" & nn & ".xls"
Set objExcelFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Server.MapPath(excelfilename))



'Do the header information
objExcelFile.writeline ("<html>")

objExcelFile.writeline ("<table border=1>")

'This header is just shown in one cell ie A1 ... I want it from a1 - n1 
objExcelFile.writeline (" <td bgcolor=#cccccc> CLIENT LEVEL - " & product_header & "</td>")
```

any other suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is outputting everything in one cell, you would need to change it to output in multiple table cells.

```
objExcelFile.writeline (" <td bgcolor=#cccccc> CLIENT LEVEL - " & header1 & "</td><td>" & header2 & "</td><td>" & header3 & </td>........")
```